# Why do I get a "unclosed parenthesis" error with this SASS line?

Tags: sass

My gulp setup yields the following error:

```
assets\styles\core\_z-indexes.scss
Error: unclosed parenthesis
        on line 2 of assets/styles/core/_z-indexes.scss
>>   mobile_menu: 40;
   ---------------^
```

Below is the content of the file in question. What's wrong with it?

```
$zIndexes: (
  mobile_menu: 40; 
);

@function getIndex($zIndexName) {
  @return map-get($zIndexes, $zIndexName);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use the semicolons in your map, separate values with commas `,` and keep the last one open.

```
$zIndexes: (
  mobile_menu: 40
);

@function getIndex($zIndexName) {
  @return map-get($zIndexes, $zIndexName);
}
```

If this is not it maybe put your `'mobile_menu'` in quotes.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using indented syntax you can get this error if your map is on multiple lines. One solution is to define your map in a `.scss` file, and utilize it in a `.sass` file.

See: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1088